# How to Set image from Camera upload folder of dropbox to ImageView in android?

Tags: android, imageview, dropbox

Hi Everyone,

I am trying to get image from dropbox "Camera upload" folder and set that image to image view in android but application force closed suddenly, I am able to get image from sd card and camera and able to set that images to ImageView, but my next need is to get the image from dropbox and set it to the ImageView, but its not working for me, If anyone having idea how to resolve this issue then please help me to solve this issue.

My Code is as below:

I added spinner to choose images from Gallery, Camera and dropbox, i am able to get images from gallery and camera but not from dropbox, please help to resolve this issue:

```
Error showing as fatal exception 
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent
 { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/Camera Uploads/2013-11-11 09.42.20.jpg typ=image/jpeg }} to activity {com.capstone.classitweetsdemo/com.capstone.classitweetsdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks in advance.

```
spnImage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        if (spnImage.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select from Gallery")) {

            imageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select image to upload."), RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        } else if (spnImage.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Capture Image")) {

            imageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            sldImgPic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//mnt/sdcard/Android/data is a private space for each app, you couldn't get files from this space

Comment: Yes i know that i am not getting file from this space, thats how i am asking how to get that file.